# How to push nested arrays into mongo db in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to **POST** Product data to mongo db using mongoose. 
**Product Model**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var productsSchema = new Schema({
  //  productId: {type: _id, required: true, autoIndex: true},
    merchantId: {type: String, required: true},
    productName: {type: String, required: true},
    productDescription: {type: String, required: true},
    uploadDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    productAttributes: [
        {
            size: {type: Number, required: true},
            colors: [
                {
                    color: {type: String, required: true},
                    qty: {type: Number, required: true},
                    price: {type: Number, required: true},
                    images: [{
                        image1: {type: String, required: true},
                        image2: {type: String, required: false},
                        image3: {type: String, required: false}
                    }]
                }

            ]
        }
    ],
    otherAttributes: {
        length: {type: Number, required: false},
        fabricType: {type: Number, required: false},
        sleeves: {type: String, required: false}

    }
});
```

**CreateProductMethod**

```
module.exports.createProduct = function (product, callback) {
    var newProduct = new Products();
    newProduct.merchantId = product.merchantId;
    newProduct.productName = product.productName;
    newProduct.productDescription = product.productDescription;
    newProduct.productAttributes.size = product.productAttributes.size;
    newProduct.productDescription.colors.color=product.productAttributes.colors.color;
    newProduct.productDescription.colors.qty=product.productAttributes.colors.qty;
    newProduct.productDescription.colors.price=product.productAttributes.colors.price;
    newProduct.productDescription.colors.images.image1=product.productAttributes.colors.image1;

    Products.create(newProduct, callback);
}; <br/>
```

**While **POSTING** data to server I am getting this exception **Cannot read Property 'color' of undefined at Function.module.exports.createProduct**
Why I am getting this error? 
Please Help.

Comment: You have to add color, qty, price and images to  `productAttributes.colors` not to productDescription

Comment: Daily sermon time gain. Do not nest arrays. This looks like your first attempt at writing a structure so you need to be aware of the limitations. See the [positional operator `$` documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to gain some insight into how this will come back and bite you.

Comment: In brief you are already running into trouble because you are traversing arrays without notating the "index" position of which item you actually want to update. Remember that "arrays are lists" and therefore have more than one thing in them. Also you have another array in the document. See ["Limitations - Multikey Indexes"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#limitations) to understand that one. Oddly enough though this structure is almost exactly the same as something I tried when I first used MongoDB. I since know better.

Comment: @Neil Lunn :I understood your point.I also gone through the links shared by you. I saw stock structure in one of the documents like this : 
`{
  _id: 1,
  item: "abc",
  stock: [
    { size: "S", color: "red", quantity: 25 },
    { size: "S", color: "blue", quantity: 10 },
    { size: "M", color: "blue", quantity: 50 }
  ]
}` . I like structure , and it can fulfill my requirement as well.But again how to push **Stock** array data.?

Answer (score 0):

You have several mistakes

1. `newProduct.productDescription` is a string, you cannot assign value to `newProduct.productDescription.size`
2. Index required for `product.productAttributes.size`, must be `product.productAttributes[0].size` or use `forEach` loop iteration
3. Index required for `product.productAttributes.colors.color;`, must be `product.productAttributes[0].colors[0].color;` or use `forEach` loop iteration

Comment: Tleukabilulu : tried  **product.productAttributes[0].colors[0].color;** , now I am to push data, but productsAttributes is getting stored as [].

Comment: I did **console.log(product.productAttributes[0].colors[0].color)** ,then it is correctly printing the value, but when I did **Console.log(newProduct.productDescription.colors.color)** , it is printing as "undefined "